# Rails cannot connect to remote database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my database.yml, I set the production part as

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: 1.1.1.1
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: production_db
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```

but when run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create` , the console shows that it tries to connect to the local db, like: `Access denied for user 'root'@'2.2.2.2' (using password: NO).` Here `2.2.2.2` is my local ip address.

I am using rails 3.2.2

Comment: try mysql -uroot -p -h1.1.1.1,can you login in your mysql?

Comment: haha. we think alike, @welsonla

Comment: in Gemfile change the gem 'sqlite3' to gem 'mysql2',and make sure you could use this info to login your mysql in terminal

Answer (score 2):

In the error message, '2.2.2.2' is the source IP. So it's not trying to connect the local db.
By default, there are several root users, such as 'root'@'localhost', 'root'@'127.0.0.1'. You need to add another one, 'root'@'2.2.2.2', to connect from 2.2.2.2. Or 'root'@'%' for connecting from everywhere.
See [Adding User Accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)

You're using MySQL, right?

Comment: Thanks, your explain is very clear. Actually it is the mysql account settings issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify network connectivity with telnet? Run this command and post the response.

```
telnet 1.1.1.1 3306
```